# Ubuntu 16.04 development cycle

Tags: development, 16.04

What does the following terms means and being a web developer which one is preferred before the stable release.

1. alpha 1
2. alpha 2
3. Feature freeze
4. UI freeze
5. kernel freeze

Please explain a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature freeze is when feature stop being added/changed.  The UI freeze is when the User Interface stops getting changed.  The kernel freeze is a deadline for kernel updates.  Exceptional circumstances may justify exemptions to any freeze, at the discretion of the release managers.  For more details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule

- If you like seeing new features added in over time and the user interface improved with updates, then you can upgrade before the feature freeze.
- If you like having features not changed after the upgrade, but seeing the user interface improved with updates, then you can upgrade after the feature freeze and before the UI freeze.
- If you like having features and the UI not changed after the upgrade, then you should upgrade after the feature freeze and the UI freeze.

BTW, the feature and UI freezes have already happened for 16.04.